# Constraint kinds: Pass multiple constraints

Tags: haskell, constraint-kinds

When I have a data type like the following in haskell:

```
data A ctx = A (forall a. ctx a => a -> a)
```

Then I can put functions that work on values of types of a given class into this datatype:

```
> A (+3) :: A Num
A (+3) :: A Num :: A Num
```

But is it also possible to put functions which have multiple constraints into this datatype? I tried this:

```
> :t ((+ 3) . succ)
((+ 3) . succ) :: (Enum c, Num c) => c -> c
> :t A ((+ 3) . succ) :: A (Enum,Num)
  Expecting one more argument to `Enum'
  In an expression type signature: A (Enum, Num)
  In the expression: A ((+ 3) . succ) :: A (Enum, Num)
```

So this doesn't work. How is it possible to do what I want, or is it impossible? I know one solution would be to use a "dummy" data type and a type family, but I don't want to do that if there is another way because of the it's complexity. Also, I this example I could have just used (+1) instead of succ, but there are more complex cases where such a transformation to just one class is not possible.

Comment: What about another typeclass like `class (Num a, Enum a) => Foo a` ?

Comment: Yeah, that would of course also work, but I don't really like making a type class just to combine two contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one way to generalize the idea of joining multiple classes into one. Although it's quite awkward to use, it works.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances  #-}
module Test where

import GHC.Exts

data (:>+<:) ctx1 ctx2 a where
  C'C :: (ctx1 a, ctx2 a) => (ctx1 :>+<: ctx2) a

data (:++:) (ctx1 :: * -> Constraint) (ctx2 :: * -> Constraint) = C

class Ctx2 c1 c2 a where
  useCtx :: c1 :++: c2 -> a -> ((c1 :>+<: c2) a -> b) -> b

instance (c1 a, c2 a) => Ctx2 c1 c2 a where
  useCtx _ a f = f C'C

fC :: (Ctx2 Num Enum a) => a -> a
fC a = useCtx (C :: Num :++: Enum) a $ \C'C  -> 3 + succ a

data A ctx = A 
  { call :: forall a. ctx a => a -> a
  }

main = print $ call (A fC :: A (Ctx2 Num Enum)) 3
```

It should be possible to use constraint aliases to define Ctx3, Ctx4, ...